# How to SEL to send a non-object type parameter?

Tags: objective-c, object, select, reflection

For exemple:

```
SEL selector = @selector(setAge:);
[self performSelector:selector withObject:18];//error
```

I only have this SEL , but I I can not get this function(setAge:).

How will I use this SEL ?

thx!!!!

Answer (score 1):

You cannot pass primitive value as a parameter withObject, you should amend your setAge: method:

```
-(void)setAge:(NSNumber*)age
{
    int intAge = [age intValue];
    ...
}
```

And call it like:

```
SEL selector = @selector(setAge:);
[self performSelector:selector withObject:@18];
```

Answer (score 0):

Use NSNumber class

```
[self performSelector:selector withObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:18]];
```